# MySQL - each total sales of all items

Tags: mysql

The following mysql query for getting total sales of each item purchased by user id 31 in 2014.

---

```
SELECT 
    op.products_name,
    ROUND(SUM( IF(MONTH(o.date_purchased) = 1, op.final_price * op.products_quantity,0)), 2) AS january,
    ROUND(SUM( IF(MONTH(o.date_purchased) = 2, op.final_price * op.products_quantity,0)), 2) AS febraury,
    ROUND(SUM( IF(MONTH(o.date_purchased) = 3, op.final_price * op.products_quantity,0)), 2) AS march,
    ROUND(SUM( IF(MONTH(o.date_purchased) = 4, op.final_price * op.products_quantity,0)), 2) AS april,
    ROUND(SUM( IF(MONTH(o.date_purchased) = 5, op.final_price * op.products_quantity,0)), 2) AS may,
    ROUND(SUM( IF(MONTH(o.date_purchased) = 6, op.final_price * op.products_quantity,0)), 2) AS june,
    ROUND(SUM( IF(MONTH(o.date_purchased) = 7, op.final_price * op.products_quantity,0)), 2) AS july,
    ROUND(SUM( IF(MONTH(o.date_purchased) = 8, op.final_price * op.products_quantity,0)), 2) AS august,
    ROUND(SUM( IF(MONTH(o.date_purchased) = 9, op.final_price * op.products_quantity,0)), 2) AS september,
    ROUND(SUM( IF(MONTH(o.date_purchased) = 10, op.final_price * op.products_quantity,0)), 2) AS october,
    ROUND(SUM( IF(MONTH(o.date_purchased) = 11, op.final_price * op.products_quantity,0)), 2) AS november,
    ROUND(SUM( IF(MONTH(o.date_purchased) = 12, op.final_price * op.products_quantity,0)), 2) AS december
FROM orders_products op
LEFT JOIN orders o ON op.orders_id = o.orders_id
WHERE customers_id = 31
AND YEAR(o.date_purchased) = 2014
GROUP BY op.products_id
ORDER BY op.products_name
```

---

And there are only 2 tables to be used.

orders_products  :  orders_id, products_id, products_name...

orders : orders_id, customers_id, date_purchased

I thought left joining two tables would give me full of NULLs for unpurchased items... but it gives me only the rows of purchased items.   How can I calculate the each total sales of all the purchased / unpurchased items?

### *update

[image]

Comment: please provide sample data and expected output

Comment: Do you have the `products` table as well? Is the `products_id` field of the `orders_products` table references to that table? Could you please post the example of the data of your tables (including the `products` if it exists)?

Comment: @FathahRehmanP  I included an exmaple. thanks.

Comment: @PeterWiggin Hope my example gives you clear info this time :) Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the row with `Protein` has the `products_id = 30`? Does unique `products_name` correspond to unique `products_id`?

Comment: @PeterWiggin Sorry, that's something I randomly inserted to show you some more items. you can ignore that. your answer on sqlfiddle was what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Your `WHERE` clause is reducing your result. You should remove it your `WHERE` clause at all or add something like this:

```
SELECT 
op.products_name,
ROUND(SUM( IF(MONTH(o.date_purchased) = 1, op.final_price * op.products_quantity,0)), 2) AS january,
ROUND(SUM( IF(MONTH(o.date_purchased) = 2, op.final_price * op.products_quantity,0)), 2) AS febraury,
ROUND(SUM( IF(MONTH(o.date_purchased) = 3, op.final_price * op.products_quantity,0)), 2) AS march,
ROUND(SUM( IF(MONTH(o.date_purchased) = 4, op.final_price * op.products_quantity,0)), 2) AS april,
ROUND(SUM( IF(MONTH(o.date_purchased) = 5, op.final_price * op.products_quantity,0)), 2) AS may,
ROUND(SUM( IF(MONTH(o.date_purchased) = 6, op.final_price * op.products_quantity,0)), 2) AS june,
ROUND(SUM( IF(MONTH(o.date_purchased) = 7, op.final_price * op.products_quantity,0)), 2) AS july,
ROUND(SUM( IF(MONTH(o.date_purchased) = 8, op.final_price * op.products_quantity,0)), 2) AS august,
ROUND(SUM( IF(MONTH(o.date_purchased) = 9, op.final_price * op.products_quantity,0)), 2) AS september,
ROUND(SUM( IF(MONTH(o.date_purchased) = 10, op.final_price * op.products_quantity,0)), 2) AS october,
ROUND(SUM( IF(MONTH(o.date_purchased) = 11, op.final_price * op.products_quantity,0)), 2) AS november,
ROUND(SUM( IF(MONTH(o.date_purchased) = 12, op.final_price * op.products_quantity,0)), 2) AS december
FROM orders_products op
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders o ON op.orders_id = o.orders_id
WHERE (customers_id = 31 
AND YEAR(o.date_purchased) = 2014) 
OR o.date_purchased IS NULL
GROUP BY op.products_id
ORDER BY op.products_name
```

Comment: That's really odd! Since I confirmed that it's working on sqlfiddle, I'll accept the answer and will work on mine a bit more. Thanks!